# Name resolution is using proxy server over my local DNS server

Tags: macos, network, dns, proxy

I'm running a local DNS server to resolve `.dev` as a testing domain on my machine, the resolution works fine and shows the proper answer through `dig` and `ping` and I can pull the home page instantly with `curl`.

The DNS server is my only configured name server in System Preferences acting as a forwarder to the corporate DNS servers.

However, in the browser the domain does not resolve properly. This appears to be because of my corporate proxy server, which is somehow taking priority in resolving over the local dns server. If I disable the proxy it resolves instantly.

I've excluded the `.dev` domain and `localhost` from the proxy in System Preferences, but still resolution is being done by the proxy server rather than my DNS server.

Can anyone help? How can I change the resolution order so that the proxy is second to my local DNS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though setting the search domains explicitly to be:

```
*.dev
corporate.com
```

In System Preferences fixes the problem. For some reason otherwise website.dev gets suffixed as website.dev.corporate.com automatically. I'm not sure why as it is already a valid domain.